# How can we get json in below format using XStream or any other parser?

Tags: java, json, xstream

In the below format my doubt is the type mentioned with every field. Can you please suggest some solution? This is a requirement from the third party who will be consuming this.

subject":{
"type":"string",
"$":"Cabinet model number?"
}

Comment: Use Jackson 2, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6542833/100836

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this using gson API from google. Wrote a custom serializer which checks the type and value and creates the JSON object based on that.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Below is how this can be done using MOXy's JSON-binding.

**Domain Model (Root)**

The `@XmlElement` annotation can be used to specify the type of the property.  Setting the type to be `Object` will force a type qualified to be written out.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class Root {

    private String subject;

    @XmlElement(type=Object.class)
    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

Since a type qualifier will be marshalled out a key will need to be written for the value.  By default this will be `value`.  You can use the `JSON_VALUE_WRAPPER` property to change this to `$`.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(3);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_VALUE_WRAPPER, "$");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {Root.class}, properties);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.setSubject("Cabinet model number?");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.

```
{
   "subject" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "$" : "Cabinet model number?"
   }
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html