# Jackson and Generics

Tags: java, jackson

How do you get jackson to parse a line in a Pojo that has a wildcard generic and taking into account the `ServiceAccount` is abstract? Already has been attempted but of course since the `ServiceAccount` class is abstract it can't serialize. I have not seen anything on google or the jackson wiki that answers this question.

```
private ServiceAccount<?>[] accounts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is Polymorphic Deserialization ([the second solution on this question accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542833/how-can-i-polymorphic-deserialization-json-string-using-java-and-jackson-library))

I'm not one hundred percent sure that this works with generics, but it certainly solves the abstract class problem. Considering Java Runtime has Type Erasure, I don't think you'll have a problem casting the parsed object.

Comment: Thanks Samuel I'll take a look at those links.

Comment: Going to accept this as the answer as it sent me down the right path for this. Thanks.