# JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization: JsonMappingException

Tags: json, spring-mvc, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I supposed that I had a parent Class **Parameter** that has 2 sub classes **ComboParameter** and **IntegerParameter**

```
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = IntegerParameter.class, name = "integerParam"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ComboParameter.class, name = "comboParam")
})
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
 public abstract class Parameter {
String regEx;
}


@JsonTypeName("integerParam")
public class IntegerParameter extends Parameter {
}

@JsonTypeName("comboParam")
public class ComboParameter extends Parameter {
List<String> values;
}
```

And I have a class that had an attribute parameter

```
class A {
@JsonUnwrapped
Parameter parameter;
}
```

The Serialization of an Object `A` throw an Exception

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unwrapped property requires use of type information: can not serialize without disabling `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNWRAPPED_TYPE_IDENTIFIERS`

And if I delete the annotation `@JsonUnwrapped` I will have a json like That

```
{
     parameter:{
          integerParam:{
               regEx: regExVal
          }
     }
}
```

And what I need is a json like that:

```
{
     integerParam:{
           regEx: regExVal
     }
}
```

**NB** I' am using Jackson 2.4.4

Comment: look for [Jackson Polymorphic Deserialization](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization)

Comment: you can find an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6543330/1066779)

Comment: I edited the question to be clearer

Comment: k, what is the problem? How you want result to be?

Comment: I need a result like that:
`{
     integerParam:{
           regEx: regExVal
     }
}`

Comment: remove `include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT` from Parmeter class and try.

Comment: The same problem persist...

Answer (score 3):

Don't think there is easy and clean solution for this problem. But here is some thoughts how you can solve it ([Gist demo](https://gist.github.com/varren/f97c902efc0f34967af651529cc51902) for both cases):

**Option 1:** Add `@JsonIgnore` above property and `@JsonAnyGetter` in the top level bean. Easy to implement but not nice to have static ObjectMapper in bean and will have to copy this code to every been with Parameter property

```
public class A {

    @JsonIgnore
    Parameter parameter;

    // can put ObjectMapper and most of this code in util class
    // and just use JacksonUtils.toMap(parameter) as return of JsonAnyGetter

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    /************************ Serialization ************************/

    @JsonAnyGetter
    private Map<String, Object> parameterAsMap(){
        return mapper.convertValue(parameter, Map.class); 
    }

    /************************ Deserialization **********************/

    @JsonAnySetter
    private void parameterFromMap(String key, JsonNode value)  {
        try {
            parameter =  mapper.readValue(String.format("{\"%s\":%s}", key,value), 
                    Parameter.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** `@JsonIgnore` property and register **custom serializer/deserializer** for root `A` class

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(A.class, new ASerializer());
module.addDeserializer(A.class, new ADeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Can't use `@JsonSerialize` above A class, because serializers and deserializers inner ObjectMapper will also use this annotation, but you need to setup it to use default serializer/deserializer and not itself recursively. Or you could implement something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405958/1032167 if your really want the annotation

And serializer + deserializer would look something like this (**Unoptimized** and just a prove of concept):

```
    /************************ Serialization ************************/

public static class ASerializer extends JsonSerializer<A> {
    private static ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void serialize(A value, JsonGenerator gen,
                          SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        Map defaults = m.convertValue(value, Map.class);
        Map params = m.convertValue(value.getParameter(), Map.class);
        defaults.putAll(params);
        gen.writeObject(defaults);
    }

}

    /************************ Deserialization **********************/

public static class ADeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<A> {
    private static ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
    private static String[] subtipes = {"integerParam", "comboParam"};

    public ADeserializer() {
        m.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    }

    @Override
    public A deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException {

        TreeNode node = m.readTree(p);

        A a = m.convertValue(node, A.class);

        // hardcoded , probably can be done dynamically
        // with annotations inspection
        for (String key : subtipes) {
            TreeNode value = node.get(key);
            if (value != null) {
                String json = String.format("{\"%s\":%s}", key, value);
                a.setParameter(m.readValue(json, Parameter.class));
                break;
            }
        }

        return a;
    }
}
```

Generic deserializer would be pretty hard to write. But this question is about serialization anyway according to the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its too late , but still posting for anyone who comes looking.
I managed to solve this using controlled serialization with [@JsonAnyGetter](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#serialization-details).
And polymorphic deserialization using **multiple** setters having different [@JsonProperty](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#property-naming) value attributes.

```java
class A {
   Parameter parameter;

   @JsonProperty("integerParam") /* DESERIALIZE if integerParam type */
   public void setParameter(IntegerParameter parameter) {
       this.parameter = parameter;
   }
   @JsonProperty("comboParam") /* DESERIALIZE if comboParam type */
   public void setParameter(ComboParameter parameter) {
       this.parameter = parameter;
   }
   @JsonIgnore /*prevent serialization using default getter, this will wrap stuff into parameter*/
   public Parameter getParameter() {
       return parameter;
   }
   @JsonAnyGetter/*SERIALIZE: use any getter to add custom wrapper as per the child class type*/
   private Map<String, Object> parameterAsMap(){
       if (this.parameter instanceof IntegerParameter)
           return Map.of("integerParam",this.parameter);
       else
           return Map.of("comboParam",this.parameter);
   }
}
```

All the type and subtypes classes will have no Type information i.e.

```java
abstract class Parameter {
    String regEx;
}
class IntegerParameter extends Parameter {
}
class ComboParameter extends Parameter {
    List<String> values;
}
```

finally we get unwrapped Jsons as following:

```json
{
  "integerParam" : {
    "regEx" : "regExIntVal"
  }
}
```

AND

```json
{
  "comboParam" : {
    "regEx" : "regExComboVal",
    "values" : [ "X", "Y", "Z" ]
  }
}
```