# Serialzing heterogeneous collection with Jackson in Java

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm using Jackson to serialize a heterogeneous list. My list is declared like this:

```
   List<Base> myList = new LinkedList<>();
```

I have classes `Aggregate` and `Source` in there:

```
    myList.add(new Aggregate("count"));
    myList.add(new Aggregate("group"));
    myList.add(new Source("reader"));
```

Those classes both implement the `Base` interface. Each class has just a single property with a get/set method: `Aggregate` has "type", and `Source` has "name".

I use this code to try to serialize the list:

```
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

    StringWriter c = new StringWriter();
    om.writeValue(c, myList);
    System.out.println(c);
```

but I find the output JSON doesn't have any indication of what type of object was serialized:

```
[ {
  "type" : "count"
}, {
  "type" : "group"
}, {
  "name" : "reader"
} ]
```

As such, I don't think I can possibly de-serialize the stream and have it work as I expect. How can I include class information on the serialized representation of each object in a heterogeneous collection such that the collection can be correctly de-serialized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I polymorphic deserialization Json String using Java and Jackson Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542833/how-can-i-polymorphic-deserialization-json-string-using-java-and-jackson-library)

Comment: Absolutely not a duplicate, as the other question doesn't involve a collection class.

Comment: As you've noticed, the problem is that "the output JSON doesn't have any indication of what type of object was serialized". That's precisely what the linked question is about, and thus its answer also solves your question.

Comment: Ok, actually it only contains _most_ of the answer. So I'll write the rest.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly described in http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization. Read it, but here are the most relevant parts.

To include type information for the elements, see section 1. There are two alternatives:

1. `om.enableDefaultTyping()` will store the class name for elements stored as `Object` or abstract types (including interfaces). See documentation for overloads. This will work with collections automatically.
2. Annotate `Base` with `@JsonTypeInfo` (e.g. `@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")`). To make this work with collections, you'll also need to tell Jackson you want to store a `List<Base>` (and see section 5):

   ```
   om.writerWithType(new TypeReference<List<Base>>() {}).writeValue(...);
   ```

   or

   ```
   JavaType listBase = objectMapper.constructCollectionType(List.class, Base.class);
   om.writerWithType(listBase).writeValue(...);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten my code working.

At first, I thought I could use `WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` to get the class information:

```
   om.writer().with(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE).writeValue(c, myList);
```

That didn't work because it only made the root item have class information, and nothing else. I had hoped it would apply recursively.

And so I had to *also* quit using `List<>` directly and wrap my `List<>` object in its own class.  Then, the base interface needs a decoration to tell it to write class info:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include= JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="class")
public interface Base {
}
```

This gets the serializer to write a "class" property with the class value in it.