# How to generate JSON and XML from same entity classes?

Tags: java, jaxb, jackson

I have the below class structure.

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Phone.class, Address.class})
abstract class ContactInfo {

}

@XmlRootElement(name="address")
class Address extends ContactInfo {
    private String street;

    public String getStreet() {
      return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
      this.street = street;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="phone")
class Phone extends ContactInfo {
    private String mobile;

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
}

class Contact {
    private ContactInfo contact;

    @XmlElementRef
    public ContactInfo getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(ContactInfo contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="user")
class User { 
    private String name;
    private Contact contact;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }
    public void setContact(Contact contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}
```

When I convert this to XML using JAXB, I am getting the below structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<user>
    <contact>
        <phone>
            <mobile>8971829749</mobile>
        </phone>
    </contact>
    <name>Halley</name>
</user>
```

Where as my JSON looks a bit different.

```
{
  "User" : {
    "name" : "Halley",
    "contact" : {
      "contact" : {
        "mobile" : "8971829749"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The root element user, and phone is not at all present in my sub JSON structure.

While JAXB is honouring the XMLRootElement annotation, Jackson is not. Any idea why and how I can rectify this?

I need to generate JSON and XML from the same entity classes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

- [@JsonRootName](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRootName.html) as class level annotation
- and `ObjectMapper` to configure serialization to use root element.

---

```
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

Using `JsonRootName` is optional unless you want to have different element name than XML.

Comment: I can use `JsonRootName` for configuring the root class. What about my other classes? In this case, `Phone` class.

Comment: why would you need `@XmlRootElement` for `Phone` class in first place.

Comment: depending upon the type, I want `address` or `phone` as the xml element after `contact`.

Answer (score 0):

As Jackson is ignoring the element name provided via `@XmlRootElement`, the Jackson annotations `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` should be used to specify which `ContactInfo` type is `Address` or `Phone`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6543330/6911095 for an example.

Comment: Can this be done without an additional property? Lets say, I want to have a different tag name for my different sub classes.