# @RequestBody mapping complex json object

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I need to convert below json to java object of @RequestBody.

```
{
    "entity": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "james"
    },
    "conjunction": "OR",
    "conditions": [
        {
            "operation": "equalTo",
            "dataKey": "department",
            "dataType": "string",
            "value": "abc"
        },
        {
            "operation": "notEqualTo",
            "dataKey": "ID",
            "dataType": "number",
            "value": "100"
        },
        {
            "operation": "notEqualTo",
            "dataKey": "name",
            "dataType": "strubg",
            "value": "jack"
        },
        {
            "operation": "between",
            "dataKey": "END_DATE",
            "dataType": "date",
            "value1": "20180502",
            "value2": "20180519"
        }
    ]
}
```

The first three element in the array correspond to below java object.

```
public class ComparisonCondition extends Condition {
    private String value;
}
```

The last element correspond below object.

```
public class BetweenCondition extends Condition {
    private String value1;
    private String value2;
}
```

They all inherit from below object.

```
public class Condition {
    private String dataKey;
    private String dataType;
    private String operation;
}
```

The spring mvc method is below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = RequestAction.FILTER, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<Student>  filter(
        @RequestBody  Filter<Student> filterConfig) {   
    return null;

}
```

The Filter object is below.

```
public class Filter<T> {
    private String conjunction;
    private T entity;
    private List<Condition> conditions;
}
```

How can I map the json to java object successfully?
Currently it report `"Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "value" (class com.ssc.rest.entity.Condition), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "dataType", "dataKey", "operation"])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I polymorphic deserialization Json String using Java and Jackson Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542833/how-can-i-polymorphic-deserialization-json-string-using-java-and-jackson-library)

Comment: Scroll to the second solution in the accepted answer

Comment: Can't you use `private List<Map<String, String>> conditions;`?

Answer (score 0):

For your error, if the jackson parser don't know a field, it throws an exception.

You can avoid it by putting the annotation :

```
@JsonIgnore(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

on the target object.

For your mapping, I recommand to you to create an object corresponding to your json input, and then do manually your mapping to your target objects.

Comment: This does not answer the question, `@JsonIgnore` wont help here because the OP wants to select implementation (either ComparisonCondition or BetweenCondition) based on the `operation` field.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing 4 variables in JSON for COndition

```
{
    "operation": "equalTo",
    "dataKey": "department",
    "dataType": "string",
    "value": "abc"
},
```

but your Java POJO has only 3 variables

```
public class Condition {
    private String dataKey;
    private String dataType;
    private String operation;
}
```

just add `value` as well it will work fine.

Bottom line is : *POJO class should have all the fields passed in JSON.*

By the way your exception is telling same thing

```
Unrecognized field "value"
```

Edit 1:

I missed BetweenCondition and ComparisonCondition

You can define the Base Class in your case `Condition` with Sub Class property and hopefully it should work

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "javaclass")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = ComparisonCondition.class),
    @Type(value = BetweenCondition.class)
})

public class Condition {
    private String dataKey;
    private String dataType;
    private String operation;
}
```

Comment: Your answer explains the error, but does not answer the actual question. Look at the hierarchy, there is `value` field in the `ComparisonCondition` class. The OP wants polymorphic deserialization

Comment: yeal, I can understand the error message, but I was wondering how to get around  this error since I have subclass which contains this value property, and I also have BetweenCondition which has value1 and value2. Can spring take care of this complex case?